# MongoDB query to distinct, sort, limit and offset

Tags: sql, mongodb

I'm looking for a Mongo equivalent of the following:

```
select distinct event_type_id from events
order by created_at desc
limit 10,20
```

The Event Mongo document is as follows:

```
{
  _id: BSON(), event_type_id: 1, created_at: Date(), other_data: {}
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) on new mongo versions. Here is the example to start from:

```
db.events.aggregate([
    {$sort:{"created_at":-1}},
    {$project:{"event_type_id":1}},
    {$group:{"_id":"$event_type_id"}},
    {$skip:10},
    {$limit:20}
])
```

Here is another approach, thanks to @JoachimIsaksson

```
db.events.aggregate([
    {$group:{"_id":"$event_type_id", "created_at":{$max:"$created_at"}}},
    {$sort:{"created_at":-1}},
    {$skip:10},
    {$limit:20},
    {$project:{"event_type_id":1}}
])
```

Comment: Is there any way of doing the distinct too?

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, trying to learn... :) Can you really group after sort and keep the order?

Comment: I was thinking something along; `{$group:{_id:"$event_type_id", ord:{ $max:"$created_at"}}},{$sort:{"ord":-1}},{$project:{"event_type_id":1}},{$skip:10},{$limit:20}` but I'm freetexting here without anything to try on :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson a SQL DISTINCT command depends on the DB but in most SQL databases it is a `$group` using the `$min` or `$max` of each field of the document. DISTINCT queries have a massive flaw that you can't decide that though, it is upto the db implementation.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes you can keep sort in a $group, check my edit

Comment: what if i need to select one element which contains max value for some field and return all values of the doc unlike group and want this for each id should i do multiple queries

Comment: @nikoss, you'd better create a new question.

Answer (score 2):

You can always do this via the aggregation framework introduced in v2.2:

```
db.col.aggregate(
    {$group: {_id: "$event_type_id", created_at: "$created_at"}},
    ($sort: {"$created_at":-1}
);
```

Something like that will group, which will be the same as distinct really, all `event_type_id` values and sort by `created_at` descending.

This should be OK but be warned that at the moment it has a 16meg output limit (atm) so if you are looking to output a huge document you might find it difficult.

#### Edit

For performance you can actually make the sort occur first using an index and then `$group`:

```
db.col.aggregate(
    { $sort: {"$created_at":-1} },
    { $group: {_id: "$event_type_id", created_at: {$first: "$created_at"}} }
);
```

This uses the `$first` ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/first/ ) operator to get the first value for that field on this group. You can also use the `$last` operator too, these of course translate to the normal `$min` and `$max` but for a sorted set.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the `$first` example. If I want to add a filter after the group, for example if I want to keep only the items that have `type` set to `true`, is it a good practice to add `type: { $first: '$type' }` to `$group` and then adding a new block `{ $match: { type: true } }`. Is this okay or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: @Matteo no in this case you would use $max since you cannot definitely say that the sorted set is the $first or $last you want so you would physically get the $max of that field in this case

Comment: The $max of what? With the boolean field it makes no sense. I mean, I have a code very similar to your example. I sort by date ("created_time") and then I want to filter the result with another field, extracting the first of the set (together with the date). The way I did it seems to work, but I don't if it's correct.

Comment: @Matteo A boolean field translates to 1 and 0, 1 for true and 0 for false. $max would always return true, however, $first could return false if the first grouped date you sort by has false for its type, but that would only be the case if dates could have different boolean values and you wanted to give precedence to true, not the first sorted

Comment: @Matteo At the end of the day I may not know enough about your data and scenario to state which is best, you may find it better to produce a question with a more detailed explanation which then can be answered.

Comment: I didn't want to open a question because this is not really a problem. Anyway now I think it's correct: I take the first date and the first boolean value (they obviously need to be of the same item, and that's why I take the first) and then I filter them with $match and I take only the ones that have the true field. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: No sorry, you are right I think. I'll open a question ;)

Comment: @Matteo If you intend to the get the first of a sorted set and that is the purpose then first is right, sorry I think I may have been over thinking the problem, I am used to problems being a lot more comlpex than that

Comment: Yes, I always want the first and then I want to keep only the ones that have that field to true. It's not difficult but confusing :P

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can combine limit and skip commands with distinct query in mongo. The below code will return the equivalent of following sql statement:

```
select distinct event_type_id from events
order by created_at desc

db.events.distinct( 'event_type_id', {}, {{createdAt: -1} })
```

After retrieving the results you may extract the subset out of it according to your need. Also you might check the following post too: [How to use Distinct, Sort, limit with mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998915/how-to-use-distinct-sort-limit-with-mongodb)

Apparently this is an open ticket on mongo community, you can check the issue too, it looks like they won't implement combination of limit and distinct for awhile https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2130

Comment: I can only find [2 parameters to distinct](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#db.collection.distinct) documented, where did you find the third? :)

Comment: javascript lets you call a method with arbitrary number of params, but this won't work.

Comment: But it gives the correct result from the shell, how can that happen?

Comment: @cubbuk It may be returning the results in insertion order, and that order happens to be what you're expecting? Does it work to reverse the order by sorting ascending?

Comment: Thats the thing I was getting results in descending or ascending order when I change the sort query.

Comment: closing curly braces is orphan here so -1