# How to get the distinct list of ids from the Mongo Collection by datetime ordering?

Tags: mongodb

How to get the distinct list of ids from the Mongo Collection by datetime ordering ?

```
DBObject queryObject = new BasicDBObject("dateTime",-1);
List<String> objects= MDB.getCollection("messages").distinct("_stdid",queryObject);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB query to distinct, sort, limit and offset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267684/mongodb-query-to-distinct-sort-limit-and-offset)

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky, because each distinct value for **_stdid** can have a different dateTime field value. Which one do you want to pick? The first, the last, the average?

You will also need to use the aggregation framework, and not a straight distinct. On the MongoDB shell, you would use (if you wanted the *first* of all the dateTime values that map to a single _stdid field):

```
db.messages.aggregate( [
    { $group: { _id: '$_stdid', dateTime : { $first: '$dateTime' } } },
    { $sort: { dateTime : -1 } }
] );
```

In Java, this looks like:

```
// create our pipeline operations, first with the $group operation
DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", "$_stdid" );
groupFields.put( "dateTime", new BasicDBObject( "$first", "$dateTime" ) );
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject( "$group", groupFields );

// then the $sort
DBObject sort = new BasicDBObject( "$sort", new BasicDBObject( 'dateTime', 1 ) );

// run aggregation
AggregationOutput output = MDB.getCollection("messages").aggregate( group, sort );
```

Comment: Hi Derick, Nice to get such a response from you. But I need a list of Document Ids where those ids should be in an Descending order based on dateTime Field. For more clarification, i am giving you MYSQL equivalent Query. SELECT distinct ids from messages where receiver='foo' order by dateTime Desc;

Comment: Do you mean _id, ids or _stdid ? You're being inconsistent with naming.